# Misunderstanding about Keras Reshape layers

Tags: tf.keras

I am not understanding the behaviour of Reshape layers. Here is a simple keras model that illustrates my problem.

```
A=tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

def get_model():
    inputs=tf.keras.layers.Input((3,))
    x=inputs
    x=tf.keras.layers.Reshape((3,))(x)
    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs,x)

model=get_model()
```

After executing this code block, if I execute

```
model(A)
```

I get A.
But if I execute

```
model(A[0])
```

I expect to get A[0]. Instead I get the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer "reshape_8" "                 f"(type Reshape).

{{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 3 values, but the requested shape has 9 [Op:Reshape]

Call arguments received by layer "reshape_8" "                 f"(type Reshape):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(3,), dtype=float32)
```

I tried to fix this behaviour calling

```
model(A[0],training=False)
```

but the error persists.

With or without 'training=False', this seems to be inconsistent with the behaviour of the trivial model obtained by removing the reshape layer:
execution of

```
A=tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])

def get_model():
    inputs=tf.keras.layers.Input((3,))
    x=inputs
    # x=tf.keras.layers.Reshape((3,))(x)
    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs,x)

model=get_model()
model(A[0])
```

prints A[0] without any complain.

If I understand well, the Reshape layers only accept batches of samples.
However, I don' t understand why the training=False option does not compensate for this at the model level.
Actually, feeding the model with a unique sample (with shape equal to the argument of the Input layer) should already enable this training=False mode, or maybe some dedicated no_batch mode.

Can anyone explain why things are designed like this and what is the standard way to bypass this obstacle, please ?